# remote stop modem_manager, enable remotely...?

Tags: systemd, services, modem-manager

If you stop modem_manager.service, will a power cycle on the unit restart it? or does it need enable modem_manager.service entered?

Answer (score 0):

The default(*unless you changed it*) unit filename is `ModemManager.service`  and not `modem_manager.service`

Systemd services have to aspects in this regard ... **started**/**stopped** and **enabled**/**disabled** ... if a service is **enabled** then this means it will be started automatically on the next reboot regardless of its state(started/stopped) in the current running system ... Check the service status with:

```
systemctl status ModemManager.service
```

Which should output something like:

```
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-05 09:08:55 +03; 5 days ago
   Main PID: 1198 (ModemManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 23669)
     Memory: 6.2M
        CPU: 1.797s
     CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
             └─1198 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
```

If that gives you `/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled`(*the default is `enabled`*) then yes, the service will be started automatically on the next reboot regardless of its current stopped/started state.

On the other hand, if the status is `/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; disabled` then you need to enable it like so:

```
sudo systemctl enable ModemManager.service
```

or otherwise, it will not be started automatically on the next reboot.